# While loop in hangman program C++

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop

```
 while (wrongGuess != 6)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter a letter to guess: ";
        cin >> wrongGuess;
        wrongGuess = toupper(wrongGuess);
        cout << "You guessed the letter: " << wrongGuess << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < fileWord.length(); i++)
        {
            if (fileWord[i] == wrongGuess)
            {
                cout << wrongGuess << " is in the letter to guess." <<       endl;
            found = true;
        }

    }
    // if not found - increment wrong guesses
    if (!found)
    {
        wrongGuess++;
        cout << wrongGuess << " is not in the word to guess." << endl;
    }
    //print the board that corresponds to the wrongGuess

}
```

the first part of the while loop is working it will display the " is in the word to guess." However when I enter an incorrect letter it does not display the " is not in the word to guess" instead it displays "You guessed the letter." What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: Your program is doing exactly what you are telling it to: (1) prompting "Enter a letter to guess: ",  (2) reading the letter (`cin >> wrongGuess`), (3) converting the guess to upper case, then (4) printing "You guessed the letter: ...". Not sure why you are expecting it to do differently. Can you clarify?

Comment: i need the program to tell me if the guessed letter is correct or not. when i enter the correct letter it tells me the letter is in the word, when i enter an incorrect, it does not tell me that the letter is not in the word instead it seems to go back to the beginning and gives me the message "you guessed the letter: "

Comment: First of all, what data type is your wrongGuess variable? It seems like you both use it as a char and as a integer.

Comment: wrongGuess is a char

Comment: Your `while` loop is checking `wrongGuess` with the number `6`. The number `6` won't match any letter that you might enter. Why is the `while` based upon that and not some other flag (like `found`)? Also, after `found = true` you need to break out of your loop, so you can use `break;`

Comment: Why did you name your input variable `wrongGuess`?  If you named it with a more descriptive and appropriate name (for example, "userGuess" or something), you more than likely would not have the issue you're seeing.  Instead, you have `wrongGuess` being a counter *and* the user input.  Shouldn't the guess be independent of the number of attempts?  Also, you never set `found` to false before the loop.  Where is this boolean set?

Comment: This is a prime candidate for firing up your [development environment's debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) and taking a walk through the code with an eye on the while loop's condition variables as you step through. If you are using Visual Studio or Eclipse, setting up the debugger is quite quick. Other toolchains I don't have enough familiarity with to comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrongGuess as the input from the user as well as a counter for the wrong guesses... 
Also, I do not know what are the types of wrongGuess and fileWord but my guess is you are comparing an int with a char which might not give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code at all, but it should set you on the way for how you design your program correct.

```
int guessedLetters = 0;
int guessLeft = 5;
while (guessLeft < 0 || guessedLetters == fileWord.length())
{
    char guessInput; 
    cout << "\nEnter a letter to guess: ";
    cin >> guessInput;
    guessInput = toupper(guessInput);
    cout << "You guessed the letter: " << guessInput<< endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < fileWord.length(); i++)
    {
        if (fileWord[i] == guessInput)
        {
            cout << wrongGuess << " is in the letter to guess." <<       endl;
            guessedLetters++;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    // if not found - increment wrong guesses
    if (!found)
    {
        guessLeft--;
        cout << guessInput << " is not in the word to guess." << endl;
     }
    //print the board that corresponds to the wrongGuess

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need another variable, you are using the wrongGuess to control the while and read the input from the user.

I don't know, but try this.

```
int count = 0;
while (count != 6)
{
    cout << "\nEnter a letter to guess: ";
    cin >> wrongGuess;
    wrongGuess = toupper(wrongGuess);
    cout << "You guessed the letter: " << wrongGuess << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < fileWord.length(); i++)
    {
        if (fileWord[i] == wrongGuess)
        {
            cout << wrongGuess << " is in the letter to guess." << endl;
            found = true;
        }

   }
// if not found - increment wrong guesses
if (!found)
{
    count++;
    cout << wrongGuess << " is not in the word to guess." << endl;
}
//print the board that corresponds to the wrongGuess
}
```